# Adding $ infront of variable within print statement in python 3.3.4

Tags: python

I have the following statement:

```
print ("You have entered the price of ",var1, "for a chocolate bar")
```

Which works happily however i need to put a '$' infront of it for the output. I tried hiding it in the print statement however then you end up with a gap between it so you end up with

```
'You have entered the price of $ 34.33 for a chocolate bar'.
```

I need it to be:

```
'You have entered the price of $34.33 for a chocolate bar'.
```

I am very new to python, and this is tripping me up.
Any help would be appreciated. Im using python 3.3.4

Answer (score 4):

`format` is the recommended way to do this.

```
print("You have entered the price of ${0} for a chocolate bar".format(var1))
```

Comment: where can I find documentation about the fact that format is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

```
print "You have entered the price of ","$"+str(var1), "for a chocolate bar"
```